# What happens if you don’t repair a leaking CV boot?

Tags: cv-boot

Car was parked up for a very long time with a ripped CV boot.

I know the i dirt and grime gets in it can mess things up.  But what exactly will happen and what symptoms should I be looking for?

Car feels funny (maybe cos it’s been brought out after a long time and maybe dragging to left a bit).  Know there’s other reasons this could happen but could it be related to anything the ripped gaiter at all?

Thanks.

Comment: You get to buy another one sooner rather than later.

Comment: Please check here: https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/is-it-safe-to-drive-with-a-damaged-cv-joint Please have it repaired promptly.

Answer (score 2):

At best, grit and dirt will get in and the joint will wear prematurely. At worst, the joint could sieze and fail at speed - there's a reason it's an MOT failure.